# It's correct to have css classes only to add jquery functionality?

Tags: jquery, html, css

We have a functionalitiy that we want, like hide a element of html, but we want it to activate this functionality with two diferents buttons of the page.

It's correct to add a class to the buttons, for example "hideElement" with no css rules, and then in jquery make:

```
    $(".hideElement").click(function(){
         $("#elementToHide").hide(); 
    });
```

Or it is incorrect or inelegant to add a css class with no css rules to the code?

Comment: Yes, it's completely valid

Comment: If it's jQuery, it's valid (pun intended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are HTML classes, not CSS class. There is no such thing as a CSS class.

Using an HTML class to mark an element as a member of a group of elements with something in common is fine and what classes are for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is valid.
But adding class to elements is good when you have more then one element with same functionality.
so if it is not the case you can use id instead of class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine.

The purpose of classes in HTML/CSS is to identify elements. You are using them for that exact purpose, so it is a valid and expected thing to do.